# How to build latest ffmpeg for android-ffmpeg project on github

Tags: android, video, github, ffmpeg

I am working on https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg project.
In this project, it uses ffmpeg version 0.11.1.
How can i build this project with the latest ffmpeg version?

I try to delete ffmpeg folder in this project. Checkout the latest ffmpeg version in url: [git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git]. After that, i ran command ./configure_make_everything.sh as normal but i got error:

```
    File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
patching file libavutil/arm/intmath.h
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
patching file configure
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg/ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
**ERROR: freetype2 not found**

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg/ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:53: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:95: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:178: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:53: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:93: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:95: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:178: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg ~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
~/workspace/android-ffmpeg
admin@ubuntu:~/workspace/android-ffmpeg$
```

I got error: Freetype2 not found but if i build with the original ffmpeg include in this project, this error is not occur.

How can i fix it? Please help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when building ffmpeg for a desktop.  In my case ffmpeg was looking for the freetype2 headers in /usr/include/freetype instead of /usr/include/freetype2.

This solution is ugly, but I created a symlink

`sudo ln -s /usr/include/freetype2/ /usr/include/freetype`

Then ./configure was succesfull.

You might be able to achieve the same by patching ffmpeg to replace all instances of

`#include <freetype/config/ftheader.h>`

with

`#include <freetype2/config/ftheader.h>`

It looks like this is just in **libavfilter/vf_drawtext.c**

Since you appear to be building for a different CPU you may need to modify the paths with the proper location for freetype2 for your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

This was almost a year ago, so I assume you're not waiting for answers, but I have one.  I forked the guardian project and updated the submodule entries.

https://github.com/touchlab/android-ffmpeg

You'll need to hand-edit the ffmpeg/configure according to the notes at the top.  Ignore the part about ffmpeg/libavutil/arm/intmath.h.

I've built this with ndk r10c.

Comment: Unfortunate, I was hoping this'd fix it, but It's already applied in the current origin. I have the same issue as op also ndk 10